# The family $\mathfrak{B}= \tau \cup \{\{x \} \mid x \in \Bbb P\}$ is a basis for some topology $\pi$ of $\Bbb R$. Show that $(\Bbb R, \pi)$ is regular

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\tau$ be the standard topology on $\Bbb R$ and let $\Bbb P = \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$. The family $\mathfrak{B}= \tau \cup \{\{x \} \mid x \in \Bbb P\}$ is a basis for some topology $\pi$ of $\Bbb R$. Show that $(\Bbb R, \pi)$ is regular.

To show regularity I'm used to using the characterization that if $x \in X$ and $U$ is a open set containing $x$, then if for $V$ open set containing $x$ we have that $\overline{V} \subset U$ the space is regular.

So trying to use this if $x \in \Bbb R$ and $U$ is a open set containing $x$ I know that there is a basis set $B \in \mathfrak B$ such that $$x \in B \subset U$$

There are only two possibilities for $B$ either it's in $\tau$ or it's an irrational singleton. If $B \in \tau$ I think I can use the fact that $(\Bbb R, \tau)$ is regular, but I don't know wheter it will work as I'm taking the closures w.r.t to the topology $\pi$?

Also if $B$ is a singleton I think I run into some issues as $x$ can be any real number not irrational neccessarily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin understanding what's going on here, notice that your open sets are basically the usual opens from $\mathbb{R}$ together with singletons consisting of irrational numbers. This has an interesting consequence: singletons of irrational numbers are now both open and closed, because every singleton is already closed with respect to the usual topology $\tau$. The topology $\pi$ also adds a bunch of new closed sets to the topology, namely every set of the form $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{x\}$, where $x \in \mathbb{P}$. But as we already discussed, every $\{x\}$ with $x \in \mathbb{P}$ is both open and closed, so every corresponding complement $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{x\}$ is also open and closed.

Now, to answer your question note that a different characterization of a regular is space is that given a closed set $C$ and a point $x$ not contained in $C$, there are open neighbourhoods of $C$ and $x$ which do not intersect. That is, $C \subset U, x \subset V$, where $U, V$ are open and $U \cap V = \emptyset$.

If $C$ is closed and $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus C$, then either $C$ is a closed with respect to $\tau$, in which case regularity follows because $(\mathbb{R}, \tau)$ is already regular, or $C$ is one of the new closed sets introduced by $\pi$. In the second scenario, there are two options. Either $C$ is simply the complement of a irrational singleton (that is, a base element), or $C$ is an arbitrary intersection of such complements. I'll treat them separately to make the idea easier to understand.

In the first case we have $C = \mathbb{R}\setminus\{x\}$ for some irrational $x$. But in this case, the only possible point outside $C$ is $x$, and we can choose the disjoint open neighbourhoods to be $C$ and $\{x\}$, since these are both open (and closed) in $\pi$.

In the second case, $C = \cap_\alpha (\mathbb{R}\setminus\{x_\alpha\}) = \mathbb{R}\setminus\{x_\alpha\}_\alpha $, where $x_\alpha$ is irrational. Again, a point outside $C$ must be one of the irrational numbers in the family $\{x_\alpha\}_\alpha$, say $x_\beta$, but now is not clear whether $C$ is open or not, since it is an arbitrary intersection of open sets. We know, however, that $C \subset \mathbb{R}\setminus\{x_\beta\}$, which is open. So we choose as neighbourhoods the open sets $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{x_\beta\}$ and $\{x_\beta\}$.

Comment: Why is $\{x\}$ for $x \in \Bbb P$ closed? I can see that it's open just because it's a basis element, but I cannot figure out why it's closed? It's closed in $(\Bbb R, \tau)$, but why is it closed in $(\Bbb R, \pi)$?

Comment: A topology is a collection of open sets, right?  and $\tau$ is simply the usual family of all open sets in $\mathbb{R}$. The topology $\pi$ from the question is the union of $\tau$ with a bunch of other sets, so everything that is open with respect to $\tau$ is also open with respect to $\pi$, because you're simply adding more open sets. Now, every point is closed in $(\mathbb{R}, \tau)$, so $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{x\}$ is $\tau$-open, and therefore also $\pi$-open. But this means exactly that $\{x\}$ is closed with respect to $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Case I: if $x\in \mathbb Q$ then an open set $U$ containing $x$ contains a basis element of the form $(a,b):a,b\in \mathbb Q.$ Choose irrational numbers $x<y$ such that $a<x<y<b.$ Then, $[x,y]$ is open in the new topology (it is a union of the open sets $\{x\},\{y\}$ and $(a,b))$ and $[x,y]\subseteq (a,b)\subseteq U.$ But $[x,y]$ is also closed in the new topology (because its complement is open.)

Case II: if $x\in \mathbb P$ then any open set $U$ containing $x$ satisfies $x\in \{x\}=\overline{\{x\}}\subseteq U.$

Comment: Can you elaborate why $\{x\} = \overline{\{x\}}$ i.e. why is the singleton closed w.r.t to the topology $\pi$?

Comment: $\{x\}$ is open in the new topology and its complement is $(-\infty,x)\cup (x,\infty)$, which is open in the new topology, so $\{x\}$ is also closed, and therefore equal to its closure (in the new topology.)